# ¿Cómo cambiar un label cuando se seleccione una opción en un select?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y necesito que por ejemplo, si el usuario escoge "ropa" el label de abajo cambie a "10000" pero lo he intentando y no me sale. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```js
function ShowSelected() { /* Para obtener el valor */
  var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;
  var txt = document.getElementById("lbl").value;
  alert(cod);
  /* Para obtener el texto */
  var combo = document.getElementById("producto");
  var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(selected);
  if (selected == "ropa") {
    document.querySelector('txt').innerText = '10000';
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto">
    <option value="ropa">ropa</option>
    <option value="zapatos">zapatos</option>
  </select>
  <label name="lbl" id="lbl"></label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

deberías poner el código en la pregunta y no en los comentarios, de todas formas la manera de editar el texto de un elemento en js es mas o menos la siguiente:

```
var label=document.querySelector('#lbl');
label.textContent='1000';
```

Hay muchas formas de seleccionar un elemento en js, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) es solo una de ellas y tambien hay muchas formas de cambiar el contenido de un elemento en js y [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) es solo una de ellas.

---

Por otro lado tu código no corre porque el select, el label y el script están  por fuera del body. Debes poner el select y el label en el body y el script lo debes poner o en el body o en el head...

en tu scrip debes cambiar esta linea

```
document.querySelector('txt').innerText = '10000';
```

por

```
document.querySelector('#lbl').innerText = '10000';
```

ya que

```
document.querySelector('txt')
```

no selecciona a ningún elemento.

Para aprender a usar los selectores puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) que tiene mozilla

UPDATE:

para que se ejecute bien este es el codigo:

```
            <html> 
            <head> 
                <title></title> 
            </head> 

            <body> 
                <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto"> 
                    <option value="ropa">ropa</option> 
                    <option value="zapatos">zapatos</option> 
                </select> 
                <label name="lbl" id="lbl">

                </label> 
                <script src="funcion.js"></script> 

                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                function ShowSelected() { 
                /* Para obtener el valor */
                    var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value; 
                    var txt = document.getElementById("lbl").value; 
                    alert(cod);
                     /* Para obtener el texto */
                    var combo = document.getElementById("producto"); 
                    var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text; 
                    alert(selected);
                    if(selected == "ropa") { 
                     document.querySelector('#lbl').innerText = '10000'; 
                    } 
                } 
                </script>
            </body> 

            </html>
```

Comment: no me corre no me cambia y eso que cambie las lineas y corregi el error con la ubicacion del script :/

Comment: mira la actualización que le hice a mi respuesta, el código lo ejecute en firefox, trata de editar tu pregunta para que sea más entendible.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !! colega me ayudaste muchisimo sorry por las molestias

Comment: vale con gusto, acepta la respuesta y como te digo trata de mejorar la pregunta para que a otras personas les pueda servir también

Answer (score 2):

Yo recomendarías que utilizaras el atributo `value` de la opción seleccionada en vez de `text` ya que puedes cambiar el texto para el usuario sin alterar la funcionalidad.

```js
function ShowSelected() { /* Para obtener el valor */
  var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;
  var txt = document.getElementById("lbl").value;  
  /* Para obtener el texto */
  var combo = document.getElementById("producto");
  var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;  
  if (selected == "ropa") {
    document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = '10000';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="ropa">ropa</option>
    <option value="zapatos">zapatos</option>
  </select>
  <label name="lbl" id="lbl"></label>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDICIÓN**

Podrías guardar el valor que vas a mostrar en el `label` en el valor de la opción del `select`

```js
function ShowSelected() { /* Para obtener el valor */
  var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;
  var txt = document.getElementById("lbl").value;  
  /* Para obtener el texto */
  var combo = document.getElementById("producto");
  var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;  
  
    document.getElementById('lbl').innerText = selected;
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto">
    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
    <option value="10000">ropa</option>
    <option value="20000">zapatos</option>
  </select>
  <label name="lbl" id="lbl"></label>
</body>

</html>
```